# Byte swapping in bit wise operations

Tags: c

I have this function called byte swap I am supposed to implement. The idea is that the function takes 3 integers (int x, int y, int z) and the function will swap the y and z bytes of the int x. The restrictions are pretty much limited to bit wise operations (no loops, and no if statements or logical operators such as ==).

**I don't believe that I presented this problem adequately so Im going to re attempt**

I now understand that

```
byte 1 is referring to bits 0-7
byte 2 is referring to bits 8-15
byte 3                      16-23
byte 4                      24-31
```

My function is supposed to take 3 integer inputs, x, y and z. The y byte and z byte on the x then would have to get switched

```
int byteSwap(int x, int y, int z)
```

ex of the working function

```
byteSwap(0x12345678, 1, 3) = 0x56341278
byteSwap(0xDEADBEEF, 0, 2) = 0xDEEFBEAD
```

My original code had some huge errors in it, namely the fact that I was considering a byte to be 2 bits instead of 8. The main problem that I'm struggling with is that I do not know how to access the bits inside of the given byte. For example, when I'm given byte 4 and 5, how do I access their respected bits? As far as I can tell I can't find a mathematical relationship between the given byte, and its starting bit. I'm assuming I have to shift and then mask, and save those to variables.Though I cannot even get that far.

Comment: It's unclear to me how exactly is it supposed to work. It'd be useful if you posted 1-2 examples of x, y and z meeting your criteria.

Comment: Casting on the left side of an `=` operator is usually a sign you're doing something wrong.

Comment: added edits to show examples on how it is supposed to work. Hopefully everything is more clear now, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Um, bytes have 8 bits each, not 2. Where did that idea come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the ith byte by using `((1ll << ((i + 1) * 8)) - 1) >> (i * 8)`. Swap using the XOR operator, and put the swapped bytes in their places.

```
int x, y, z;
y = 1, z = 3;
x = 0x12345678;

int a, b; /* bytes to swap */
a = (x & ((1ll << ((y + 1) * 8)) - 1)) >> (y * 8);
b = (x & ((1ll << ((z + 1) * 8)) - 1)) >> (z * 8);

/* swap */
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;

/* put zeros in bytes to swap */
x = x & (~((0xff << (y * 8))));
x = x & (~((0xff << (z * 8))));

/* put new bytes in place */
x = x | (a << (y * 8));
x = x | (b << (z * 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say the *'the y and z bytes of x'* this implies x is an array of bytes, not an integer. If so:

```
x[z] ^= x[y];
x[y] ^= x[z];
x[z] ^= x[y];
```

will do the trick, by swapping `x[y]` and `x[z]`

After your edit, it appears you want to swap individual bytes of a 32 bit integer:

On a little-endian machine:

```
int
swapbytes (int x, int y, int z)
{
    char *b = (char *)&x;
    b[z] ^= b[y];
    b[y] ^= b[z];
    b[z] ^= b[y];
    return x;
}
```

On a big-endian machine:

```
int
swapbytes (int x, int y, int z)
{
    char *b = (char *)&x;
    b[3-z] ^= b[3-y];
    b[3-y] ^= b[3-z];
    b[3-z] ^= b[3-y];
    return x;
}
```

With a strict interpretation of the rules, you don't even need the xor trick:

```
int
swapbytes (int x, int y, int z)
{
    char *b = (char *)&x;
    char tmp = b[z];
    b[z] = b[y];
    b[y] = tmp;
    return x;
}
```

On a big-endian machine:

```
int
swapbytes (int x, int y, int z)
{
    char *b = (char *)&x;
    char tmp = b[3-z];
    b[3-z] = b[3-y];
    b[3-y] = tmp;
    return x;
}
```

If you want to do it using bit shifts (note `<<3` multiplies by 8):

```
int
swapbytes (unsigned int x, int y, int z)
{
    unsigned int masky = 0xff << (y<<3);
    unsigned int maskz = 0xff << (z<<3);
    unsigned int origy = (x & masky) >> (y<<3);
    unsigned int origz = (x & maskz) >> (z<<3);
    return (x & ~masky & ~maskz) | (origz << (y<<3)) | (origy << (z<<3));
}
```

Comment: X is supposed to be an integer. I added some edits to hopefully make it more clear, I apologize for the confusion

Comment: ... and, dear downvoters, the problem here is precisely what? Yes, it's artificial, but so is the question.